# Сравнение номера телефона

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Помогите решить задачу.

Есть два номера:

```
1.380990856601
2.380503027100
```

Задача состоит в следующем. Нужно сравнить любые 5 подряд идущих цифр в первом номере со вторым и если они совпадают, тогда отреагировать как-то.

Как можно сравнить любые пять подряд идущих цифр?

Comment: Нужно проверить что любые пять подряд идущих цифр в первом номере и такие же 5 подряд идущих цифр во втором совпадают

Comment: Вот в этом и сложность.

А если 5 первых не совпадают, а совпадают 5 вторых?

Comment: Мужик, тебя ж русским по белому просят НОРМАЛЬНО сформулировать задачу - так, чтобы никаких непоняток не осталось и **не надо было задавать дополнительные вопросы**. Чтобы задачу можно было понять ТОЛЬКО ТАК, как ты её понимаешь, и никак иначе. Продумай - и откорректируй текст вопроса.

Comment: звучит как частный случай задачи поиска https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наибольшая_общая_подстрока а решений этой задачи полно на всех языках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему бы просто не взять все группы по 5 цифр из первого номера,
Длинна первого номера 12-5 = 8 групп, проверить включает ли второй номер любую группу из первого, также сделать со вторым, если оба не содержат ни одну из 8 групп получившихся из другого номера - тогда выдаешь несоответствие, иначе выдаешь соответствие.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, но будет работать только с 2 элементами в массиве, если будет больше - код нужно допиливать:

```
<?
    $arr = [
        '380990856601',
        '566013027100'
    ];
    $newArr = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $number){
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
            $newArr[$key][] = substr($number, $i, 5);
        }
    }
    //Выведет те, которые совпали
    var_dump(array_intersect($newArr[1], $newArr[0]));
?>
```

Comment: Во первых, что мешает сравнивать 8 комбинаций символов всех номеров из массива? Во вторых, было написано про 2 номера.

Comment: @Shiki в чем, собственно, претензия к моему ответу?

Comment: Ну, ваш код не является универсальным, начиная от длинны массива, заканчивая длинной номера. На втором как раз и можно погореть.